# How do I capture this value using Regex?

Tags: c#, .net

I have this text: "`Showing: 16 of 11543 course results`"

I want to capture 16 and 11543. This value could differ but their position will always be the same. I could split this text but it doesn't look nice, and can lead to bugs in future. Is there any way I could achieve this using `Regex`?

Comment: `Showing: (\d+) of (\d+) course results` - For future reference, plug that in here: http://regexhero.net/tester/ and click ".net" for generated code.

Comment: somebody is serial downvoting me

Comment: I did not, however the expectation is that a question shows what's been tried rather than simply asking  *how do I ...*

Comment: @CodeCastle: SO doesn't give any proof. I think you were one of them since you seem agitated. I already did effort but it was using *Split* and I didn't post it here since it was irrelevant as I wanted do it using Regex but had no clue of how to do. Posting concise question seems to be my way.

Comment: @Andreas: please calm down. I said exactly the opposite to what you are blaming me. Please read my question again

Comment: @Andreas: deleted his comment :-/

Comment: @Jack My bad. In that case you really are just lazy. 3 SO results when googling on this subject

Comment: @Jack You're funny Jack. Downvoting my answers on other questions because you can't take justified criticism. Also it hardly takes more effort since you apparently did not bother learning the very basics of regex, nor combined the knowledge available in those first 3 links. All of it is easily enough to solve your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the regex:

```
Showing: (\d{1,10}) of (\d{1,10}) course results
```

Capture group is your first number, capture group 2 is your second number. Capture groups are defined by the brackets `()` , the `\d` is capturing digits, and the number in the curly braces defines the possible length of the digits to be captured.

So in this case it will detect number that consists at least of 1 and maximum of 10 digits.

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string yourInputString = "Showing: 16 of 11543 course results";
        Match match = Regex.Match(yourInputString, @"Showing: (\d{1,10}) of (\d{1,10}) course results", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        if (match.Success)
        {
            string firstNum = match.Groups[1].Value; // 16
            string secondNum = match.Groups[2].Value; // 11543
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There are so many ways to resolve this... another one that finds all digit-groups:

```
string text = "Showing: 16 of 11543 course results";
Regex re = new Regex("(\\d+)");
MatchCollection mc = re.Matches(text);
foreach(var match in mc) 
{
  Console.WriteLine(match);
}
```